# Starting Percentage for Native Language?

Tags: rifts

In Rifts, how do you determine the starting percentage for your characters native language? The Language skill states "...other than your native language", so it seems like I wouldn't use those percentages. But I can't find any other mention of native language in the Core Rulebook or by scouring a few sites.

If it's applicable, I'm a Wilderness Scout with an IQ of around 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The skill Language: Native Tongue appears on page 304 of the *Rifts Ultimate Edition* (right above the skill Language: Other), has a Base Skill of 88%, and increases by +1% per level of experience.

Comment: Thanks. We were using a different edition and couldn't it anywhere.

Comment: be careful there are some interesting differences between the normal rifts and the Ultimate Edition. I love playing Crazy OCC but in RUE they removed the Crazy Hero :'( which my favourite option when I turned level 4.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the character's skill with the native tongue is listed in the appropriate OCC/RCC description under OCC/RCC skills.

Comment: I looked there as well. We must be using a really old edition, because it wasn't listed there.